# Text with space entered via tinymce editor showing unexpected behaviour at front end

Tags: php, joomla-2.5, view

in one of my component record entry form i placed a editor which use tinymce from joomla configuration. i save record by entering some texts for a description field like "description description description description description  description description" which as u see i placed a space after each word in editor by pressing keyboard space key.

but when it is displayed in front end, text does not break on space upon exceeding the width in percent in table td so is it's showing text crossing the limit of my table width to right breaking template width.

So are those actually spaces when texts added with space via tinymce editor??. When i add text manually in front end component view file without outputting description field then i see text breaks in space. I checked mysql database table too for description field and don't see any characters replaced space.

So where is the problem when i display text in front end with space entered by tinymce editor at backend that it do not break in space upon width limit exceeded??

Comment: Do you have the **Entity Encoding** set to **raw**

Comment: Where? If in editor plugin settings then all are set as default but line break as <br> and advanced parameters.but all i will check soon as offline now.

Comment: Have you checked the html output on your browser in conjunction with the css?

Comment: @Lodder entity encoding in plugin settings set to raw.It's look like a global problem as i created a joomla default article and displayed in front end, same behaviour too.

Comment: Is this limited to tinyMCE entries or have you tried another editor like JCE?

Comment: It's impossible to be certain without viewing the html output, it could be that the table styles are preventing the text wrapping. Why are you using a table in your form? If you are using a table to get a specific layout, then that is almost certainly incorrect. Tables should be used to display tabular data.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried jce editor? 
I always replace the default with this one and work s fine for me.
https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your CSS code contains `white-space: nowrap;` somewhere, thus forcing the text to be displayed in a single line within your table.

You should also check your source code to see if the text

```
description description description description description description description
```

is rendered within `<pre>` tags.

I hope this helps you find your solution.